# Adding information to a cell based on form submission with IF statement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to get apps script to fill Column L with store address based on Location in Column D.

This is my current script:

```
function sendEmails() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow, 11)
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];

        var message =

            "<p><b>Date: </b>" + row[0] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Name: </b>" + row[1] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Title: </b>" + row[2] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Location: </b>" + row[3] + "</p>" ;


        var cell = row[9];

        if (cell == "") {
            var subject = "***Service Request for "+ row[1] +  " ***";

            MailApp.sendEmail({
                to: "davidm@",
                subject: subject,
                htmlBody: message,
                noReply: true,
            });

            var setRow = parseInt(i) + startRow;
            sheet.getRange(setRow, 10).setValue("Sent");




        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I am using this to populate the data manually:

```
=iferror(index('Store Data'!A:N,match(D6,'Store Data'!A:A,0),14),)
```

What would be my best and most efficient route for adding that information into the column automatically?

```
function sendEmails() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow, 11)
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];

        var message =

            "<p><b>Date: </b>" + row[0] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Name: </b>" + row[1] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Title: </b>" + row[2] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Location: </b>" + row[3] + "</p>" ;


//////// New Script test ////////////


if (row[3] = "Nashua NH") {
  var Location = "Address 1";
    }
    else if (row[3] == "Salem NH") {
  var Location = "Address 2";
    }

   else {

  }

//////////////////////////////////////



        var cell = row[9];

        if (cell == "") {
            var subject = "***Service Request for "+ row[1] +  " ***";

            MailApp.sendEmail({
                to: "davidm@",
                subject: subject,
                htmlBody: message,
                noReply: true,
            });

            var setRow = parseInt(i) + startRow;
            sheet.getRange(setRow, 10).setValue("Sent");
            sheet.getRange(setRow, 12).setValue(Location);




        }
    }
}
```

The above is what I have tried but does not seem to work.  What am I missing here?  With this, It adds only address 1 to all rows

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me how your data is structured, so I don't immediately see how best to retrieve the information and use it in the script, but at least, there is a missing "=" sign in your first if clause in your "New Script Test" section. It should read `row[3] == "Nashua NH"`

Comment: And @BenoîtWéry for the win.  That was it... so simple.  Ive been staring at this for hours and missed that every time.  Thank you]

Comment: Typical, I've been blocked on things like that so many times. Second pair of eyes is very useful in such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (row[3] = "Nashua NH")
```

is always going to be "true" since you're assigning the value. There is a missing "=" there.